# Jqgrid sorting and "no records message" not working

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I need to implement two features: 1) show some kind of message for when no data is coming and 2) be able to sort the DataPoints column. Should be fairly straight forward but the features are not working. Here is my grid definition:

```
 $('#myGrid').jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            jsonReader: als.common.jqgrid.jsonReader('Standard'),
            url: als.common.getServerPath() + 'ZscoreAjax/getData',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['MethodCode','Lab', 'Standard', 'Nom. Val.', 'Mean', '%RSD', 'Data points', 'Z-score', 'Sorter', 'LDL', 'UDL'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'MethodCode', index: 'MethodCode', width: 37, search: false, title: false, align: 'center', hidden:true},
                { name: 'LabCode', index: 'LabCode', width: 30, search: false, title: false, hidden:true },
                { name: 'Standard', index: 'Standard', width: 80, search: false, title: false },
                { name: 'NomVal', index: 'NomVal', width: 100, search: false, title: false, align: 'center' },

                {
                    name: 'Mean', index: 'Mean', width: 50, search: false, title: false, align: 'center'


                },
                { name: 'RSD', index: 'RSD', width: 50, search: false, title: false },
                { name: 'DataPoints', index: 'DataPoints', width: 50, search: false, title: false, align: 'center', sorttype: 'int'},
                { name: 'Zscore', index: 'Zscore', width: 50, search: false, title: false, align: 'right' },
                { name: 'Sorter', index: 'Sorter', width: 50, search: false, title: false, align: 'right' },
                { name: 'LDL', index: 'LDL', width: 50, search: false, title: false, align: 'right', hidden: true },
                { name: 'UDL', index: 'UDL', width: 50, search: false, title: false, align: 'right', hidden: true }
            ],
            autowidth: true,
            sortable: true,
            sortname: 'DataPoints',
            scroll: false,
            hidegrid: false,
            height: 200,
            width: 500,
            rowNum: 50,
            ignoreCase: true,
            altRows: true,
            emptyrecords: "No records to display",
            altclass: 'gridAltRowClass',
            loadComplete: function (data) {


            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datatype is local, but in the same time you try to get data from server using the option url. You should set either datatype json or xml or if you have datatype local you should provide a local data array(parameter data) as described into the docs depending on your jqGrid version used.

Comment: I have other grids that are defined the same way and the sorting works fine there. Do I need a pager for sorting?

Comment: I reset the datatype to json later when the grid getting populated. All our apps use this model and it works fine. I am not rewriting the whole application.

Comment: Is there a way to capture the user click on the column header and do a manual sort? I need this feature working.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: One of the problem can be in the data provided, but it is not published here. Maybe if you prepare on-line example we can help. Also which version of jqGrid is used